# 2017 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Mathematica's [second moderator election](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/election/2) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: Kuba]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Also, please join me in thanking [Verbeia](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/users/8/verbeia) who is stepping down from the moderator position after [many years of service](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/election/1). They also were instrumental during the beta period in setting Mathematica on the course toward graduation. Thank you, Verbeia!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/election/2), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/6649141371338752/0).

Comment: "They"...? Does it mean that both candidates were elected?

Comment: @IstvánZachar: It's an example of [singular they](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they).

Comment: @JonEricson I already suggested this in chat. With one mod stepping down, wouldn't it be an idea to promote MarcoB as well? After all, it was a very close call and both are good candidates for the job.

Comment: @halirutan: We had planned the election because Verbeia was stepping down, so that doesn't really change things. We always make sure elections are competitive. If there are as many slots as candidates, we normally extend the nomination period for a  week to make sure voters have a real choice. So while I don't disagree MarcoB seems an excellent candidate, we'll run a new election the next time we need a new moderator.

Comment: @JonEricson OK, that wasn't clear to me from the start. I only saw that it is now a null-sum game and we don't have an *additional* mod. Thanks for clearing this up.

Comment: The summary report link appears to have an expired security certificate...  My browsers red flag it.